# pandas.read_csv : load only certain columns and the unnamed index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While working with a large dataset, I would like to load only a part of it (more precisely - I would like to load only the training data samples) as loading the full dataset takes some time and memory. I know the names of the columns of interest, but the index column is unnamed. The trouble is that (to my knowledge) the `usecols` parameter of `pandas.read_csv()` takes either column names or column numbers - I don't know if/how I could mix the two.

For no I bypass it in a somewhat cumbersome way:

```
#load only the columns of the dataset
cols = pd.read_csv('dataset.tsv.gz', sep='\t', index_col=0, nrows=0).columns  

#find the positions of the columns of interest (those in my_columns_list) 
colnums = np.nonzero(cols.isin(my_colmuns_list))[0]

#shift column numbers by one and insert 0 for the index column
colnums = np.insert(colnums+1, 0, 0)

#read the dataset
X = pd.read_csv('dataset.tsv.gz', sep='\t', index_col=0, usecols=colnums)
```

Obviously, an alternative solution could be load the full dataset, name the index column (e.g., 'index_column'), resave the dataset and simply use:

```
X = pd.read_csv('dataset.tsv.gz', sep='\t', index_col=0, usecols=['index_column'] + my_columns_list)
```

but then this operation would have to be repeated every time that I deal with a new dataset (names of the samples for `my_columns_list`, are known independently, from the response variable.)

Comment: wrap all the information in a function. ie `my_read_csv(*args, **kwargs, usecols = None)` and use this function teach time you want to read your data thus preventing the repeated operations

Comment: Usually, subjects correspond to rows, not columns. Is there a good reason to have subjects encoded in columns, not in rows?

Comment: @nemo that's correct - the data is transposed after loading. It is genomic data with hundreds of samples, but millions of rows.

Answer (score 1):

I would load the dataset with the desired column names (usecols) and using index_col=False, by adding at the beginning of my_columns_list 'Unnamed: 0':

```
my_columns_list = ['Unnamed: 0'] + my_columns_list
X = pd.read_csv('dataset.tsv.gz',
                sep='\t',
                index_col=False,
                header=0,
                usecols=my_columns_list)
```

I try to illustrate it with the following toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
tsv = f"""\tsub0\tsub1\tsub2\tsub3
   0\t0\t1\t2\t3
   1\t10\t11\t12\t13
   2\t20\t21\t22\t23
   3\t30\t31\t32\t33"""

f = open('toto.tsv', 'w')
f.write(tsv)
f.close()
my_columns_list = ['sub0', 'sub3']
my_columns_list = ['Unnamed: 0'] + my_columns_list

df_all = pd.read_csv('toto.tsv',
                     index_col=False,
                     sep='\t',
                     header=0)
print(df_all)
```

This outputs (when loading the whole dataset):

```
     Unnamed: 0  sub0  sub1  sub2  sub3
0             0     0     1     2     3
1             1    10    11    12    13
2             2    20    21    22    23
3             3    30    31    32    33
```

Now, by letting index_col set to False, you can give the desired column names as usecols parameter:

```
df_selected = pd.read_csv('toto.tsv',
                  index_col=False,
                  sep='\t',
                  header=0,
                  usecols=my_columns_list)
print(df_selected)
```

which outputs:

```
     Unnamed: 0  sub0  sub3
0             0     0     3
1             1    10    13
2             2    20    23
3             3    30    33
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, 'Unnamed: 0' is a default name that pandas give to unnamed columns (with appropriate numbers)? Good to know.

Comment: That's correct. I hope it doesn't depend on pandas version